# CScript Error: Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\plugins\check_files.vbs"

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-server-2012, nagios

I am trying to execute a VBScript Nagios plugin: `check_files.vbs`.
I can execute the VBScript plugin on the Windows 2012 server. It works when I run locally.

I cannot get the script to execute if a call is issued from Nagios Core.
It does execute correctly, it looks like, from Nagios server, it finds the plugin, attempts to execute, but cannot find the Windows Script Engine!

From Nagios Core Server call:

```
[root@alpcts000001083 libexec]# ./check_ncpa.py -v -H 3.239.245.147
    -t gold3726 -M plugins/check_files.vbs -a '-p "D:\Delta 
    Incoming\IncomingData\PersistentStore\Delta IBM MQ Series" -w 100 -c 200'
Connecting to:
    https://3.239.245.123:5693/api/plugins/check_files.vbs/-p/%22D%3A%5CDelta%20Incoming%5CIncomingData%5CPersistentStore%5CDelta%20IBM%20MQ%20Series%22/-w/100/-c/200?token=gold3726&check=1
    File returned contained:
    {
        "returncode": 1,
        "stdout": "CScript Error: Can't find script engine \"VBScript\" for
        script \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nagios\\NCPA\\plugins\\check_files.vbs\"."
    }
    CScript Error: Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\plugins\check_files.vbs".
    [root@alpcts000001083 libexec]#
```

It connects, calls, and can't locate the Script Engine, returns response to Nagios.

From the Windows Client 2012 server

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\plugins>check_files.vbs -p
    "D:\Delta Incoming\IncomingData\PersistentStore\Delta IBM MQ Series" -w 100 -c 200
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    
OK: 27 files were matched.|count=27
```

I have tried:

```
cd %windir%\system32
regsvr32 vbscript.dll
regsvr32 jscript.dll
```

Changing the registry:

```
HKCR\CLSID\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\InprocServer32
C:\Windows\system32\vbscript.dll
wscript.exe //H:cscript
```

I'm not a Windows person, mostly Unix/Linux, it is looking like to me, and I don't know... It is something to do with the User. I think when the call comes in to Windows the System user calls the plugin. I don't know how to make the system recognize the Script Engine.

Comment: In August, MS disabled VBScript execution (in IE, the default https protocol handler) for sites in the Internet Zone.  Try adding "3.239.245.123" to your "Local intranet" security zone on the server.  Check the %PATH% environment variable for the context in which the script runs, and ensure C:\Windows\system32 is listed; and check %PATHEXT% to ensure .VBS is listed.  Also, try disabling any anti-virus script scanning plugins.  Finally, it's bad practice to use https against IP addresses, since the certificate rarely has the IP address listed, causing certificate failures on name matching. HTH.

Comment: thank you LeeHarvy1, greatly appreciate your response!  I will try these and let you know.  I won't be able to do this til later this afternoon.  thanks again

Comment: For regedit 32, instead of `cd %windir%\system32 ...` try `cd %windir%\SysWOW64 ...`. It _is_ a difference on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: thank you all, all very good suggestions.  I did it all w/o resolve.  I called the Windows team in company, they have done exactly what we have done here.  and it works now???? permissions? IDK.